# How to escape + in post call content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, content-type, url-encoding

I have a ajax call with content type:
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

Now I have a data like:
"firstName=bob+builder";

When the data is sent to the server the browser replaces the + sign with space and the data goes as firstName: bob builder

Is there a way to escape that + sign? as far as I know there is no way except that it should be handled on the server side, replacing space with + sign. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to encode on the client side. With Javascript:

```
encodeURIComponent("bob+builder"); //bob%2Bbuilder
```

The server side code should then simply decode.

Comment: Thanks, So what all things should be escaped for application/x-www-form-urlencoded apart from + and space.

Comment: You should encode all strings, as that will ensure that your application is secure. For example, a user could provide "&something=else" as the value for firstName, which if left unencoded, would be interpreted by the server as an additional variable called "something" with the value of "else".